# Remove red underline: GetDepartmentsByDepartmentID

Tags: c#

```
public MyUniversity GetDepartmentsByDepartmentID(string department)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Departments WHERE DepartmentID ='" + department + "'";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    MyUniversity deprtmnt = new MyUniversity();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        deprtmnt.code = reader["Code"].ToString();
        deprtmnt.title = reader["title"].ToString();
        deprtmnt.credit = reader["Credit"].ToString();
        deprtmnt.description = reader["Description"].ToString();
        deprtmnt.semester = reader["Semester"].ToString();


        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
        return deprtmnt;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an incomplete question; Please fix your code formatting and provide an explanation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that `not all code path return value`. Reason is that in the scope of your loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    /* Code */
    return deprtmnt;
}
```

If code doesn't enter `while` loop then there is no return statement. 
move the return to be outside of the loop's scope:

```
MyUniversity deprtmnt = new MyUniversity();
while (reader.Read())
{
    /* Code */
}
return deprtmnt;
```

*Read about [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) as using string concatenation for sql queries is susceptible for sql-injections*

- *[Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/6400526)*